# REST PATCH failure

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, web

For the following code :

```
updateUser: function(id, user){

            var updateUrl = "/Users/" + id + "/"

            var promise = $http({method:'PATCH', url: updateUrl, data: user, headers: {'segment' : segment, 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }})
                .error(function(data, status){
                    return {"status":false};
                });

            return promise;
        },
```

And the REST endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}/",
produces = { "application/json" }, 
method = RequestMethod.PATCH)

public ResponseEntity<User> patchUser(
@PathVariable("userId") String userId,


@RequestBody HashMap userMap
)
  throws NotFoundException {

  return service.patchUser(userId,userMap);
 }
```

I get the following error : Error patch user feign.FeignException: status 415 reading UsersApi#patchUser(String,HashMap); The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

Any ideas?

Comment: `415` means `unsupported media type`. For the'Content-Type': 'application/json', do you have JSON parser like `Jackson` added to the application ?

Comment: You're requesting application/xml while the endpoint states that it produces application/json, hence the exception

Comment: Sorry, just a typo i get the same error for : 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'

Comment: Can you check the response headers content type? What is it?

Comment: As I understand the error, it says that you're sending the data in an unrecognized format

Comment: I am sending in an application/json. I just checked